# Decomposition of Representations of $S_n$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\lambda,\mu$ be a partitions of $n$, $T^\lambda$ the set of $\lambda$-tabloids and
$\varphi^\lambda:S_n\to GL(\mathbb{C}T^\lambda)$ be the permutation representation and $\psi^\mu:S_n\to GL(S^\mu)$ the Specht representation.

I know that $\varphi^\lambda=\psi^\lambda\oplus\bigoplus_{\mu\trianglerighteq\lambda}m_\mu\psi^\mu$, my question is, how can I compute the $m_\mu$ in specific cases?

For example, if $\lambda=(3,1^2)$ then $\varphi^{(3,1^2)}=\psi^{(3,1^2)}\oplus m_{(5)}\psi^{(5)}\oplus m_{(4,1)}\psi^{(4,1)}\oplus m_{(3,2)}\psi^{(3,2)}$ and we can use the degrees using the hook length formula to get an equation for the $m$'s:
$$20=\deg\varphi^{(3,1^2)}=\deg\psi^{(3,1^2)}+m_{(5)}\deg\psi^{(5)}+m_{(4,1)}\deg\psi^{(4,1)}+m_{(3,2)}\deg\psi^{(3,2)}=6+m_{(5)}\cdot 1+m_{(4,1)}\cdot 4+m_{(3,2)}\cdot 5$$
but that gives 9 (I think, haven't computed them all) possible solutions for $(m_{(5)},m_{(4,1)}, m_{(3,2)})$. I also tried to use Frobenius reciprocity to compute the different multiplicities, but I couldn't come up with a way to write the different representations as inductions or restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want the multiplicities of Specht modules in the permutation module. These are given by Young's rule, and appears in all standard sets of lecture notes and books about symmetric groups. The coefficients $m_{\lambda,\mu}$ in the decomposition are equal to the number of semistandard tableaux of shape $\lambda$ and type $\mu$, and are called the *Kostka numbers*.

[Wikipedia has a write-up about it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kostka_number)

Comment: Hey, sorry for being ambiguous. I slightly edited the question to make it clearer. I saw Young's rule in a few lecture notes I found online, but all of them omitted the proof which leads me to believe that there is a more elementary approach to this problem. I am not looking for a general formula, just a method that allows one to compute the multiplicities in a given example (like the one in my question).

Comment: @14159 The proof is about two pages, and is elementary. Young's rule gives you an expression for the coefficients. In a specific case you can simply work out the permutation character, compute the character table and take inner products if you want. But there is no secret simpler way to do things than Young's rule that we don't tell people about.